# Clean Ubuntu Desktop install, Network is unreachable

Tags: networking, 20.04, system-installation, network-manager, ethernet

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on a PC (Motherboard: PRO Z690-A DDR4(MS-7D25), BIOS E7D25IMS.100). First of all, it has a NVIDIA graphics card so for now I can only access a console (I need to update packages to get everything to work, I think). In the terminal, I cannot update anything, because the Ethernet is not working.

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8 
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
 *-network UNCLAIMED
      description: Ethernet controller
      product: Intel Corporatoin
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
      version: 03
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
      configuration: latency=0
      resources: memory:44600000-446fffff memory:44700000-44703fff
```

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:15f3] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:7d25]
        Kernel modules: igc
```

```
$ cat /etc/netlan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When I search in the BIOS for 'net', the only option I get is UEFI network stack for optimizing ipv4, and the setting is disabled.

How can I fix this? If you need any more information, I'll be happy to provide

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, using an external WiFi dongle. With plugging it in, I could install all the necessary updates, and from there the Ethernet adapter also worked. I still wonder why the Ethernet didn't work from the start, but this fix works fine for me. I think it is the fault of the motherboard manufacturer, since I see that more people online have this problem.